# what is the below statement explains

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, properties, nullable

`public virtual int? NoRw { get; set; }`

here what is then data type int? specifies with the property NoRw why we need to use like this

Answer (score 4):

Nullable integer:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s(v=vs.80).aspx

> A nullable type can represent the normal range of values for its underlying value type, plus an additional null value.

Answer (score 4):

`int?` is shorthand for `Nullabe<int>`.

[Nullable<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx) is a value type, and the generic type parameter must also be a value type.

A nullable type can contain a value, or no value at all e.g.

```
int? i; // same as Nullable<int> i;
Console.WriteLine("i.HasValue={0}", i.HasValue); // Writes i.HasValue=False
i = 10;
Console.WriteLine("i.HasValue={0}", i.HasValue); // Writes i.HasValue=True
```

You can use the ?? operator (i.e. the [null-coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx)) with Nullable types.

```
int? i; // i has no value
// Now we want to add 10 to i, and put it in a, however
// a = i + 10 cannot work, because there is no value in i
// so what value should be used instead?
// We could do the following
int a = 10;
if(i.HasValue)
   a += (int)i;

// or we could use the ?? operator, 
int a = (i ?? 0) + 10; // ?? returns value of i, or 0 if I has no value
```

The ?? operator allows us to use nullable types and directly supply a meaningful alternative if there is no value.

Answer (score 2):

```
public virtual int? NoRw { get; set; }
```

NoRw is virtual Nullable integer property

other example

```
Nullable<int> variable= null;
or
int? variable= null;
```

Check this post for more detail : [Nullable type -- Why we need Nullable types in programming language ?](http://pranayamr.blogspot.com/2010/12/nullable-type-why-we-need-nullable.html)